# Archive Directory Using Zpaq

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, compression

I am trying to setup a backup system for a server that I manage to improve upon the old system. I am choosing [zpaq](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) because it provided good compression with the old system using `lrzip -z` and because the linked page claims to offer incremental compression in which only changed data is backed up in each new backup instance.

I am currently using the following script to make the backup (all data is stored in the `server` directory):

```
cd server
zpaq pa ../backup.zpaq *
```

This script produces an archive that includes all of the files that are directly below the server directory but does not recursively scan the entire directory system. How can I make it scan the entire directory system?
When I remove the `a` option or backup the `server` directory from it's parent the issue still occurs.

The [man page](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaqdoc.html) that seems to be written by the author of the tools says:

> If a name is a directory, then it recursively includes all files and subdirectories within.

Ubuntu's [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/zpaq.1.html) makes no mention of recursion. I have installed the tool from Ubuntu's repository using `apt-get install zpaq`. If Ubuntu's zpaq is somehow different from the one I linked at the beginning of this question please explain where an Ubuntu package for the linked zpaq can be found.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a solution
that gets `zpaq` to work the way you expect it to. 
But, if you’re using `bash`,
this workaround should get you the result you want. 
Type `shopt -s globstar`. 
Then, do the command you’ve been using, with one small change:

```
zpaq pa ../backup.zpaq **
```

With `globstar` mode in effect,
`**` expands to a list of entries in the current directory *tree*;
i.e., the current directory and below. 
Like `*`, it will ignore **`.`** (hidden) files. 
If you want to include them, do `shopt -s dotglob` too. 
(You can combine these into one command: `shopt -s globstar dotglob`.)

It’s most convenient to do this in a script. 
But, if you do it in your main (interactive) shell,
you may want to undo the `shopt` settings. 
You can do this with `shopt -u globstar dotglob`.

Note: If you have too many files,
this might fail because there is a limit to the length of a command line —
but it’s pretty large.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04.3. The solution is to not use the Package from the repository but rather install the latest source from http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html

After downloading the package it is in a .zip format and will need to be unzipped using unzip. From there just do:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Now doing

```
zpaq a *archive* */dir*
```

will include the directory and all of its sub-directories and files.